# Unable to import seaborn and sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, seaborn

I can't load seaborn and sklearn despite having the packages installed. I already restarted the kernel. I'm importing on spyder v4.2.4

[image]

When I try to import seaborn and sklearn, the console tells me "no module named 'seaborn'

[image]

Please advise me on how I can check for the potential issue and resolve. Thanks! :)

Comment: did you activate the conda env? , if not use `conda activate`

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that Anaconda prompt and your IDE are using the same python libraries?

You can check Anaconda like this

```
(base) C:\Users\username>where python
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

Check some module that you can install by running `.__file__` to see where it's being loaded from

```
os.__file__
Out[5]: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\os.py'
```